# deserializing json with a changable key

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "data":
        {
            "110714":{"periphery_id":108},
            "110715":{"periphery_id":102},
            "110710":{"periphery_id":107}
        }
}
```

and classes that describe it:

```
public class Info
{
    [JsonProperty("periphery_id")]
    public int PeripheryId { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty(//what should be here as i have keys like 110710,110715,110714)]
    public Info Info { get; set; }
}

public class Structure
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

How can I describe these objects by one class?

```
"110714":{"periphery_id":108},
"110715":{"periphery_id":102},
"110710":{"periphery_id":107}
```

I know the values of all of the numeric keys that would be in the JSON because I send them in a server request.

API server is external and can`t modify JSON structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the values in data has changing keys you could use a Dictionary to map it up to, so instead of Data having an object of Info it would have a `Dictionary<int, Info>` from which you can then access the values

Answer (score 0):

As Gronex suggested use Dictionary. But to make it work you need to implement custom json converter by inheriting JsonConverter and override ReadJson method.